Suppressing warnings for all files in a specific folder in Visual Studio
How  to suppress a single warning e.g. CS1591 for all files in a single folder?
e.g I only wont suppress all warnings in folder Areas not in the full project.
I have tried:
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\*.cs">
    <NoWarn>CS1591</NoWarn>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>

But it is not working? Are there any solutions.
And i dont wont edit all files in Area with
#pragma warning disable 1591
..
#pragma warning restore 1591


If you want to suppress e.g. the CS1591 warning in all cshtml.cs files from a specific folder, you can do so by creating an .editorconfig file. Place this file in the directory where you want to suppress the warning and add the following content:
[*.cshtml.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.CS1591.severity = none

This configuration in the .editorconfig file ensures that the CS1591 warning is suppressed for all cshtml.cs files in that directory.
